# Верстаю впервые макет, подскажите ошибки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Попытка вёрстки:

---

http://ip.16mb.com/pub/Organic/

---

Конкретно что мне не нравится:

верстка при масштабировании съезжает, что, естественно, плохо.

в разных браузерах отображение гуляет, значительно (думаю,указывает на большие ошибки в коде)

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> верстка при масштабировании съезжает, что ессно не есть гуд.

Да, это первое, что я бы добил. Это не очень сложно - нужно просто поиграться с процентным указанием размеров и всякими `min-width`. Наверное, стоило бы проработать и динамику - при наведении на ссылку она должна так или иначе подсвечиваться, например.

Я бы принципиально не использовал `<br/>` - это не запрещено, и в тех местах вряд ли будет динамический контент (т.е. можно сверстать раз и навсегда). Очень хотелось бы изменить способ наименования классов - верхний регистр не использует вообще никто, чаще всего используют схему `ох-как-приятно-заменять-пробелы-дефисами`, для наименований используют англоязычные названия, а сами названия должны быть максимально уточняющими - если это какой-то конкретный список, то, возможно, он и называться должен `information-link-list`.

Последнее, про что хотел бы сказать - это семантика. Списки (например, ссылок) должны лежать в `<ul>`, навигация - в `<nav>`, футер - в `<footer>`. Этим вы не только пишете красивый код, но и помогаете роботам постичь структуру документа.

Comment: Спасибо! Будем учится.

Answer (score 0):

Для первого раза неплохо.
На меня сейчас накинутся и сожрут, но я бы посоветовал использовать [bootstrap](http://mybootstrap.ru/). Таким образом вы сразу получите адаптивность верстки и кучу других плюшек. Да, у бутстрапа есть свои минусы, но в целом это очень удобный фреймворк.

Comment: Планировал изучить, правда, немного позже.